# How to fill a distance between two meshed as filled cells/mesh in pyvista?

Tags: python, grid, distance, mesh, pyvista

So I look at this [sample](http://docs.pyvista.org/examples/01-filter/distance-between-surfaces.html#sphx-glr-examples-01-filter-distance-between-surfaces-py) and I want to create a mesh/surface grid that fills that distance. How to do such a thing in PyVista?

What I try and seem not to be able to bridge with Andras Deak beautiful [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68207991/1973207):

```
import pyvista as pv
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from scipy.spatial import KDTree
import PVGeo
from PVGeo import interface
from PVGeo.filters import BuildSurfaceFromPoints

b = pv.read('./top.vtk') # PolyData
t = pv.read('./bottom.vtk') # PolyData

dim = (int(b.bounds[1]-b.bounds[0]), int(b.bounds[3]-b.bounds[2]), 1)
z_range =  np.arange(b.bounds[4], b.bounds[5] )
bottom = BuildSurfaceFromPoints().apply(b)
top = BuildSurfaceFromPoints().apply(t)

grid_2d = top.points.reshape(dim[:-1] + (3,), order='F')[..., :-1]
```

That sadly fails on line with grid_2d  with

> ValueError: cannot reshape array of size 1942464 into shape
> (30150,26750,3)

Comment: Do you mean something like a [terrain following mesh](https://docs.pyvista.org/examples/00-load/terrain-mesh.html#sphx-glr-examples-00-load-terrain-mesh-py)?

Comment: Yes, I do - but on both sides...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know if there's a built-in way to interpolate between two surfaces, but it's not very hard to do so using just numpy.

Here's an example that uses [Perlin noise](https://docs.pyvista.org/examples/01-filter/sampling_functions_2d.html) to generate two sheets of data on the same grid in two different heights. The actual code for the answer comes after.

```py
import numpy as np
import pyvista as pv

# generate two sheets of input data
noise = pv.perlin_noise(2, (0.2, 0.2, 0.2), (0, 0, 0))
bounds_2d = (-10, 10, -10, 10)
dim = (40, 50, 1)
bottom, top = [
    pv.sample_function(noise, dim=dim, bounds=bounds_2d + (z, z)).warp_by_scalar()
    for z in [-5, 5]
]

# actual answer starts here
# the top and bottom sheets are named `top` and `bottom`
# and they share the same 2d grid

# rebuild grid points
grid_2d = top.points.reshape(dim[:-1] + (3,), order='F')[..., :-1]
values_x = grid_2d[:, 0, 0]
values_y = grid_2d[0, :, 1]

# generate full grid with equidistant interpolation in each (x, y)
nz = 10
scale = np.linspace(0, 1, nz)
scale_z = scale[:, None] * [0, 0, 1]  # shape (nz, 3)
scale_z_inv = (1 - scale[:, None]) * [0, 0, 1]  # shape (nz, 3)
z_bottom = bottom.points.reshape(dim[:-1] + (3,), order='F')[..., -1]  # shape (nx, ny)
z_top = top.points.reshape(dim[:-1] + (3,), order='F')[..., -1]  # shape (nx, ny)
interpolated_z = scale * z_bottom[..., None] + (1 - scale) * z_top[..., None]  # shape (nx, ny, nz)

grid_2d_in_3d = np.pad(grid_2d, [(0, 0), (0, 0), (0, 1)])  # shape (nx, ny, 3)
final_grid = grid_2d_in_3d[..., None, :] + interpolated_z[..., None] * [0, 0, 1]  # shape (nx, ny, nz, 3)
mesh = pv.StructuredGrid(*final_grid.transpose())

# plot the two sheets and the interpolated grid
pv.set_plot_theme('document')
plotter = pv.Plotter()
plotter.add_mesh(bottom, show_scalar_bar=False)
plotter.add_mesh(top, show_scalar_bar=False)
plotter.add_mesh(mesh, style='wireframe')
plotter.show()
```

[image: plot with two Perlin noise surfaces and a dense grid in between]

Comment: What one must change to fit  PolyData into the bottom and top?

Comment: Updated question with the problem I face trying to bridge PolyData loading of surfaces and your answer. Please help

Comment: @DuckQueen you'll need to be more specific then. Are the polydata points on a rectangular grid? Are the top/bottom meshes on the same 2d grid, and if not do they at least share the 2d size?

Comment: polydata points are on a rectangular grid that is nearly identical to your top and bottom images; top and bottom were generated from the same resolution so they do look nearly identically to your image

Comment: @DuckQueen OK. So it seems like you didn't reconstruct the size of the grid correctly. The error suggests that your `dim` would imply 806512500 points, but your grid only has 647488 points. Chances are your original grid doesn't use every integer value, but rather there are steps. Side note 1: even with dense integer steps you'd probably want `bounds[1] - bounds[0] + 1` (because values [1, 2, 3] have 3 - 1 == 2 but 3 points). Side note 2: do you need the `BuildSurfaceFromPoints`? Can't you just use `b.points`? `pv.read` should already give you the mesh.

Comment: @DuckQueen if you generated the original grid manually then you can probably call `np.unique` on the x and y components of the `points` array and find the number of unique values in either direction. This might not work if the grid was generated automatically, for instance for `pv.Plane()` the `z` components are not exactly 0 so you don't get a single 0 value from `unique`. Worth a shot though.