# How to join 2 surfaces on Z acess into one mesh?

Tags: python, mesh, pyvista

So I have 2 surfaces (PolyData in PyVista) one on top of another:

[image]

They are shaped a little differently on Z access yet whenever a top one has a Z value on X, Y plane we are sure a-bottom one has the same. So how one can merge two surfaces X, Y aligned into one solid mesh?

---

What I try:

```
import numpy as np
import pyvista as pv

import vtk

def extruder(mesh, val_z):
    extrude = vtk.vtkLinearExtrusionFilter()
    extrude.SetInputData(mesh)
    extrude.SetVector(0, 0, val_z)
    extrude.Update()
    extruded_mesh = pv.wrap(extrude.GetOutput())
    return extruded_mesh

# generate two sheets of input data
noise = pv.perlin_noise(2, (0.2, 0.2, 0.2), (0, 0, 0))
bounds_2d = (-10, 10, -10, 10)
dim = (40, 50, 1)
bottom, top = [
    pv.sample_function(noise, dim=dim, bounds=bounds_2d + (z, z)).warp_by_scalar()
    for z in [-5, 5]
]
bottom = bottom.extract_surface(nonlinear_subdivision=5)
top = top.extract_surface(nonlinear_subdivision=5)

top =  extruder(top, -50).triangulate()
bottom =  extruder(bottom, 50).triangulate()

intersection = bottom.boolean_cut(top)

#top = top.clip_surface(bottom, invert=False, compute_distance=True)

#top =  top.extrude([0, 0, -50]).triangulate()
#bottom =  bottom.extrude([0, 0, 50]).triangulate()
#intersection = bottom.boolean_cut(top).triangulate()
p = pv.Plotter()
p.add_mesh(top, cmap="hot", opacity=0.15)
p.add_mesh(bottom, cmap="RdYlBu", opacity=0.15)
p.add_mesh(intersection, cmap="Dark2", opacity=1)
p.show()
```

What do I get:
[image]

What I expected:
[image]
only middle to be filled.

Comment: Before I or someone else writes an answer based on the limited information available, you should add a [MCVE]. A small example with two `PolyData` surfaces that resemble the topology of your real meshes. It doesn't have to be huge (the smaller the better), and it shouldn't need real data, but it should demonstrate how your data is laid out. Otherwise this is mostly a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68200041 so unless you can clarify (and specify) this question, we might as well close it as a duplicate.

Comment: Of course as long as the (x, y) points are shared between the two meshes, it's always possible to generate points in between. But if you want the end result to be a `StructuredGrid` then more information is necessary. In other words, connectivity between the points would be too difficult to put together.

Comment: @AndrasDeak: yeah I got into trouble having the generated GRID being so big it gets out of RAM exception. So I seek an option to get to a unified hollow mesh (not using a filled GRID)

Comment: @AndrasDeak: added sample code of my problem

Answer (score 1):

So had to do this:

```
import numpy as np
import pyvista as pv

# generate two sheets of input data
noise = pv.perlin_noise(2, (0.2, 0.2, 0.2), (0, 0, 0))
bounds_2d = (-10, 10, -10, 10)
dim = (40, 50, 1)
bottom, top = [
    pv.sample_function(noise, dim=dim, bounds=bounds_2d + (z, z)).warp_by_scalar()
    for z in [-5, 5]
]
bottom = bottom.extract_surface()
top = top.extract_surface()

topm =  top.extrude([0, 0, -50]).triangulate().clean()
bottomm =  bottom.extrude([0, 0, 50]).triangulate().clean()


topm = topm.clip_surface(bottom, invert=False)
bottomm = bottomm.clip_surface(top, invert=True)
intersection = topm.boolean_add(bottomm).triangulate().clean().subdivide(2).clean()

p = pv.Plotter()
#p.add_mesh(topm, cmap="hot", opacity=0.15)
#p.add_mesh(bottomm, cmap="gnuplot2", opacity=0.15)
p.add_mesh(intersection, cmap="Dark2", opacity=1)
p.show()
```

the resulting mesh is really bad, yet it has desired shape and gets to be computed in usable time:
[image]

Comment: Good idea sticking the two halves together. It's indeed hacky, but I can't come up with anything right now myself :)

Comment: @AndrasDeak: There is in pyvista ‘boolean_cut’ method that had to save me from ‘clip_surface’ operations yet it seems not to work somehow at all for such case…

Comment: Yeah, I've never quite understood how the boolean methods work. None of them seem to do what I'd expect them to do based on the name. I suspect some of the issue here is that your mesh is "hollow" before cutting. Perhaps with a dense mesh it would work better. But you mentioned that you can't put the dense mesh in memory, so it doesn't really matter either way.

Comment: Yes, this works for me now;) even for giant region sized with meter precision;)